# Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'String'

Tags: swift, string, integer

I have to show the int value in the label, but such an error occurs in the cell. This code is a cell code and a model code. And there is also an error 'Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage''. How do I solve this error?

```
var RankingData: RankingModel! {
        didSet { setUpView() }
    }
    
    private func setUpView() {
        self.RankingLbl?.text = RankingData.ranking
        self.profileImage?.image = RankingData.profileImage
        self.nickNameLbl?.text = RankingData.nickName
    }
```

This is my cell code

self.RankingLbl?.text = RankingData.ranking error : Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'String'

self.profileImage?.image = RankingData.profileImage error : Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage'

```
    var ranking: Int = -1
    var nickName: String = ""
    var profileImage: String = ""
    
    enum RankingModelKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ranking
        case nickName
        case profileImage
    }
}
```

This is my model code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error describes, you can't assign a value of `Int` to `String`. You need to create the value of same type as below,

```
private func setUpView() {
    self.RankingLbl?.text = "\(RankingData.ranking)"
    self.profileImage?.image = UIImage(named: RankingData.nickName)
    self.nickNameLbl?.text = RankingData.nickName
}
```

You can check [Type Safety and Type Inference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) here for better understanding.